# Searchkick Elasticsearch - How to use operator - and/or for phrase queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

Let's say I have the following query string that the user enters - "white shoes and water washable"

Basically I want to search for both "white shoes" and "water washable" in my `product_description` field which is defined as `searchable`. How do I do that?

And also the same goes for "white shoes or water washable", so instead of "and" operator, use a "or" operator.

I was hoping to do something like the following but doesn't seem to work??

`Product.search ["white shoes", "water washable"], match: :phrase, operator: "and/or"`

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this like me you need to use query string, see: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1390